# Deleting old cache and data for tableview via date/time limit

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, tableview

So here's a personal challenge I've been going through that I would love help on. From the Big Nerd Ranch iOS book (3rd edition), I'm currently looking into editing and improving upon their chapter 29 Nerdfeed project (I have attached a google drive link below to download the entire project). I would like to be able to remove all items that are before a certain time period at my will. Say (hypothetically speaking) the feed for this application provided you with posts from yesterday. I don't want those posts to be stored anywhere in my application and want to ensure that ONLY the posts created today display in the application. Does anyone know how to go about this? I've been attempting to use the following snippet of code I wrote to cut out the older feed/items. Unfortunately, placement of this code is becoming a hassle and I can't seem to get rid of everything (from the cache, table data, and from the fetched data). The real problem takes into effect when trying to remove the items from the tableview via animations (consistent out of bounds errors).

```
if ([[[channelCopy items] lastObject] class] == [BNRItem class]) {

    NSDate *cutOffDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:kfeedCutOff*24*60*60];
    NSLog(@"Response: %d",[[[[channelCopy items] lastObject] publishDate] compare:cutOffDate]);
    while (([[channelCopy items]lastObject] != NULL) && ([[[[channelCopy items] lastObject] publishDate] compare:cutOffDate] == NSOrderedAscending)) {
        NSLog(@"Removed: %@", [[channelCopy items] lastObject]);
        [[channelCopy items] removeLastObject];
    }
}
```

within fethEntries I've attempted adding in the following snippets:

```
int itemDelta = newItemCount - currentItemCount;
if (itemDelta > 0) {
    NSMutableArray *rows = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < itemDelta; i++) {
        NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        [rows addObject:ip];
    }

    [[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:rows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
}
else if (itemDelta < 0) { //Removes outdated cells from the tableView
    NSLog(@"We have a problem");
    NSMutableArray *rows = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i > itemDelta; i--) {
        NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(i + currentItemCount) inSection:0];
        [rows addObject:ip];
    }
    [[self tableView] deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:rows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
}
```

I have heard that tableViews NEED at least one row inserted if you remove at the zero mark... which I've tried doing as well. Any thoughts?

[Project Link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_1MmjVEMIQnS1NNMGdrbDM5NWc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: CoreData + NSFetchResultController + NSManagedObject who handle a date  objet. Then it's a kids play to get your object the way you want them sorted. And NSFetchResultController is really made for this. Because what you are doing now is a little kind of ugly ;)

Comment: It's ugly when attempting to remove items.... I've never looked into NSFetchResultController before. Is it only meant to be used alongside core data? This application does not rely heavily on Core Data. It caches data through NSCoding protocols. I'm pretty sure that overhauling the way mentioned would take a major overhaul. Is that honestly the route to go?

Comment: Mmmmmm... actually no. Let's say, if you only to do this one time for this one code. But it will be really more challenging than using a NSFetchedResultController. I think you can be able to make something "simple" with a NSPredicate, if it's only about post date.  That can works for 100 / 200 entries max; but if you have, let's say 10000 entries, this technique will be slow. So yes, you can use simple NSPredicate instead.

Comment: Why would I use NSPredicate when everything needed for comparison is stored as NSDates? There are numerous NSDate methods as shown above for this purpose. Not only that, but my question is more so how to delete old dates from the table views data and the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Because, let's say you have only dates into your tableview; And you want to remove all dates inferior to current time.

```
NSDate* date            = [NSDate date];

// SELF will means "date" into the context. "SELF >=" equal to compare NSOrderedAscending
// predicate will be used into a mutable array of dates.
NSPredicate *predicate  = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SELF >= %@)", date];

// this array is used for the tableView display
[myMutableArrayForTableView filterUsingPredicate: predicate];

// Since tableview use myMutableArrayForTableView , now you can update the content:
[(UITableView*)self.view reloadData];
```

See, 4 lines of codes. You should use NSpredicate because you don't need to reinvent the wheel.
But i have spoiled you now you know the answer ;)

Comment: That is a great way to look into it and I wasn't per say trying to reinvent the wheel (the noted method though does look a lot cleaner!). My main issue wasn't filtering through it (as the method I have still works). It was more or less focused on placement. I can't seem to find the right areas to filter this information out without causing the table, cache, table data source to all be in proper sync. Once I find out where placement should be, I was planning on refining my method.